# Why does unlist() turn date types into numeric?

Tags: r

When I unlist a list of dates it turns them back into numeric. Is that normal? Any workaround other than re-applying as.Date?

```
> dd <- as.Date(c("2013-01-01", "2013-02-01", "2013-03-01"))
> class(dd)
[1] "Date"
> unlist(dd)
[1] "2013-01-01" "2013-02-01" "2013-03-01"
> list(dd)
[[1]]
[1] "2013-01-01" "2013-02-01" "2013-03-01"

> unlist(list(dd))
[1] 15706 15737 15765
```

Is this a bug?

Comment: From `?unlist`: *Where possible the list elements are coerced to a common mode during the unlisting, and so the result often ends up as a character vector. Vectors will be coerced to the highest type of the components in the hierarchy NULL < raw < logical < integer < real < complex < character < list < expression: pairlists are treated as lists.*

Comment: yep I did read the manual.... they're already in a common mode

Comment: Read the second line.

Comment: aha.... okay. Not a great behaviour of unlist though. This should also apply to the non list. Behaves differently on a list or a vector as you can see in the example.

Comment: Also from `?unlist`: For your first part, when `dd` is an atomic vector, this is why the results are not different: *x can be an atomic vector, but then unlist does nothing useful, not even drop names.*

Comment: okay - I guess I have to read through reams of quirky behaviour documentation for each function that I use.

Comment: I agree the behaviour is not normal. But it's *always* recommended to read the documentation of the function you're using.

Comment: @Arun I don't see why that's relevant. Date vectors are internally integers so the problem really is that attributes are stripped. The documentation doesn't mention this explicitly, but there's no way unlist could preserve attributes in general.

Comment: @hadley, I don't quite get what's (ir)relevant. The first comment?

Comment: @Arun yes, the first comment.

Comment: In essence, as long as it's a vector, `unlist` does nothing (no drop of attributes as well). And if it's a list, then `attributes` can't be preserved.

Comment: @Arun yes, because `unlist` returns non-list inputs unchanged. It doesn't seem at all blurry to me, but the documentation should mention what happens to attributes.

Comment: Yes, I just realised that (hence the delete). got it. thanks.

Answer (score 119, accepted):

`do.call` is a handy function to "do something" with a list. In our case, concatenate it using `c`. It's not uncommon to `cbind` or `rbind` data.frames from a list into a single big data.frame.

What we're doing here is actually concatenating elements of the `dd` list. This would be analogous to `c(dd[[1]], dd[[2]])`. Note that `c` can be supplied as a function or as a character.

```
> dd <- list(dd, dd)
> (d <- do.call("c", dd))
[1] "2013-01-01" "2013-02-01" "2013-03-01" "2013-01-01" "2013-02-01" "2013-03-01"
> class(d) # proof that class is still Date
[1] "Date"
```

Comment: This answer would be greatly improved if you could add a little more detail explaining what you are doing, so others will find it more readable later.

Comment: Why `"` around `c`?

Comment: @AlessandroJacopson the quote is not necessary (although see help file of `do.call`) but can sometimes be handy for functions which need to be quoted, e.g. `do.call("+", as.list(c(1, 1)))`.

Comment: Nice answer. Comment in passing if someone was looking for this (google took me here on a tangential search): I had a nested and "vertical" list and found ``t(d.call("c", mylist))`` a nice combo to get the list displayed horizontally, rather than vertically, without losing data types in the process (as you would with ``unlist()``).

Comment: another nice approach is to perform the conversion from list to vector with `Reduce`, i.e  `Reduce("c",dd)`

Comment: @OriolPrat, that calls `Reduce` n-1 times, where n is the length of the list. This will perform horribly with larger vectors, analogous (actually, identically) to why building a list/vector iteratively is a poor performer.

Comment: Thanks for the code. Doesn't answer the question, tho: why does unlist kill dates?

Answer (score 21):

## Using base R

```r
dd <- list(as.Date(c("2013-01-01", "2013-02-01", "2013-03-01")))
```

You could use [`do.call()`](https://rdrr.io/r/base/do.call.html):

```r
dd |> do.call(what = c)
```

Or [`Reduce()`](https://rdrr.io/r/base/funprog.html):

```r
dd |> Reduce(f = c)
```

## Using purrr

The popular package [purrr](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/) also provides convenient functions to flatten a list to a vector preserving types.

Most prominently, [`list_c()`](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/list_c.html):

```r
dd |> purrr::list_c(ptype = vctrs::new_date())
```

Or alternatively, [`reduce()`](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/reduce.html):

```r
dd |> purrr::reduce(c)
```

## Evaluation

All of the above calls result in a vector of [dates](https://rdrr.io/r/base/Dates.html):

```
 Date[1:3], format: "2013-01-01" "2013-02-01" "2013-03-01"
```

But performance-wise, there are differences. Base R functions are clearly faster on such a small dataset:

```r
bench::mark(do.call = do.call(c, dd),
            Reduce = Reduce(c, dd),
            `purrr::list_c` = purrr::list_c(dd, ptype = vctrs::new_date()),
            `purrr::reduce` = purrr::reduce(dd, c))
```

```
# A tibble: 4 × 13
  expression         min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result
  <bch:expr>    <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm> <list>
1 do.call         5.38µs   6.83µs   135601.        0B     40.7  9997     3     73.7ms <date>
2 Reduce          1.69µs   2.18µs   399913.        0B     40.0  9999     1       25ms <date>
3 purrr::list_c  22.92µs   28.3µs    33846.    49.9KB     37.3  9989    11    295.1ms <date>
4 purrr::reduce   58.1µs  69.34µs    13427.   236.2KB     27.7  6312    13    470.1ms <date>
# ℹ 3 more variables: memory <list>, time <list>, gc <list>
```

With a more representative sample of 99999 dates, the purrr functions catch up, but still don't come near `Reduce()`. `do.call()` on the other hand falls behind:

```r
l <- list(rep(as.Date(c("2013-01-01", "2013-02-01", "2013-03-01")), times = 33333))

bench::mark(do.call = do.call(c, l),
            Reduce = Reduce(c, l),
            `purrr::list_c` = purrr::list_c(l, ptype = vctrs::new_date()),
            `purrr::reduce` = purrr::reduce(l, c))
```

```
# A tibble: 4 × 13
  expression         min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result
  <bch:expr>    <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm> <list>
1 do.call       562.13µs 641.19µs     1387.    3.05MB     84.2   280    17    201.9ms <date>
2 Reduce          1.67µs   1.88µs   494861.        0B      0   10000     0     20.2ms <date>
3 purrr::list_c  97.73µs 142.73µs     5492.  781.29KB     81.4  1957    29    356.3ms <date>
4 purrr::reduce  57.39µs  69.46µs    12696.        0B     12.4  6156     6    484.9ms <date>
# ℹ 3 more variables: memory <list>, time <list>, gc <list>
```

Comment: This is brilliant!

Comment: This calls `c` "length minus one" times, so it works just fine being called _twice_ vice once, but if you have a long list this might be demonstrably slower (mostly due to re-allocation, not due to `c` itself).

Comment: @r2evans: I've added benchmarks, so people can judge for themselves :)

Comment: (1) Benchmarks with a length of 3 is overwhelmed by other overhead. I tested with length 1000. (2) You never define `l`. If `l <- list(dd)` (using the original `dd` _vector_), then indeed `Reduce` is faster, suggesting `do.call` has overhead (which is surprising to me). If `l <- as.list(dd)` (which may be used when derived programmatically in other ways), then `do.call` wins. So my comment stands, but definitely based on assumptions on your incomplete code.

Comment: Thanks, you're right, I've updated the benchmarks. The differing performance implications of `list(dd)` vs. `as.list(dd)` I can confirm, but I didn't include this info above.