# R apply to change date in Posixct?

Tags: r, posixct

I'm trying replace the date in some Posixct data I have in a df. Essentially I thought of using something like this:

```
as.POSIXct(sub("\\S+", "2018-07-02", x))
```

x being the value in the row of my original data frame. I thought that the most efficient way would be to use something like apply to iterate through the rows, something like:

```
apply(df$original.date,1,function(x) as.POSIXct(sub("\\S+", "2018-07-02", x)))
```

However, it doesn't seem to like it, giving me an error regarding positive length. I was wondering first of all whether my approach was sound, and if so how to fix it. Alternatively I'm all ears if there is a better approach.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The functions `sub` and `as.POSIXct` are vectorized, hence a *single* call

```
df$original.date <- as.POSIXct(sub("\\S+", "2018-07-02", df$original.date))
```

will replace the `original.date` column in the data frame.

As for your `apply` code:

```
> apply(df$original.date,1,function(x) as.POSIXct(sub("\\S+", "2018-07-02", x)))
Error in apply(df$original.date, 1, function(x) as.POSIXct(sub("\\S+",  : 
  dim(X) must have a positive length
```

The problem is that `apply` expects a matrix or array, while you give it a column from a data frame, i.e. a vector. You could use `lapply` or `sapply`. But that is unnecessary since as shown above the entire column can be changed in one go.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I managed to get to change each date individually, I was really trying to get an apply answer as this would make changing them through the df much easier. I guess an alternative would be to make a loop but I was trying to avoid that.

Comment: Please see the expanded answer. I do not understand why you want to use apply in this case.

Comment: Apologies, I had misread your script. That seems to work. Thank you :). Out of interest. Could I see what the lapply approach would look like please, would it be the same as the script above but replaced with lapply?

Comment: `lapply(df$original.date, function(x) as.POSIXct(sub("\\S+", "2018-07-02", x)))` together with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15659783/why-does-unlist-kill-dates-in-r for getting a vector from a list.