# Date column coerced to numeric when indexing dataframe with [[ and a vector

Tags: r, date, dataframe, purrr

I am creating a data.frame with a column of type `Date`. When indexing the data frame with `[[` and a numeric vector, the Date becomes a number. This is causing a problem when using `purrr::pmap`. Can anyone explain why this is happening and is there a work around?

Example:

```
x <- data.frame(d1 = lubridate::ymd(c("2018-01-01","2018-02-01")))

class(x$d1)
# [1] "Date"

x[[1]]
# [1] "2018-01-01" "2018-02-01"

x[[c(1, 1)]]
# [1] 17532
```

Comment: try using `purrr:map_df`.. (I think) `map` turns the df to a matrix, casting the POSIXct to character..

Comment: I meant to say pmap. now edited.

Comment: Turns out this is an ongoing issue: https://github.com/tidyverse/purrr/issues/358

Comment: Yes, did you note [@hadley's comment there](https://github.com/tidyverse/purrr/issues/358#issuecomment-363091446)?

Comment: You mean that this is a base R issue (which makes sense given my example). I guessed at the issue from the traceback:`.f(cost_name = .l[[c(1L, i)]], cost_value = .l[[c(2L, i)]], cost_start = .l[[c(3L, 
    i)]], cost_end = .l[[c(4L, i)]], cost_inflation = .l[[c(5L, 
    i)]], period_type = .l[[c(6L, i)]], ...)`

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why `x[[c(1, 1)]]` instead of `x[1, 1]`?

Comment: the `x[[c(1,1)]]` is how `purrr::pmap` appears to be accessing the value as it iterates through the data.frame. This is where I encountered the issue above.

Comment: From `help(Extract)` - *Subsetting (except by an empty index) will drop all attributes except names, dim and dimnames.*  Keep in mind that *subsetting* is different from *indexing*.  In `x[[1]]` you are indexing, in `x[[c(1, 1)]]` you are subsetting and hence attributes lost.

Comment: Dunno about the terminogy here, but at least in `?Extract` they call `z[[c(1, 2)]]` recursive _indexing_. And class `Date` is preserved when extracting from an nested list: `z <- list(a = list(x = 1, date = as.Date("2018-01-01")), b =  as.Date("2018-02-01"))`; `z[[c(1, 2)]]`. Not from the second 'non-nested' slot though: `z[[c(2, 1)]]`...

Answer (score 5):

## Overview

After reading [why does unlist() kill dates in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15659783/why-does-unlist-kill-dates-in-r) and the documentation of [`unlist()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.5.1/topics/unlist), you've got to manually prevent [`purrr::map()`](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/map.html) from coercing the Date objects to integer by way of using the [`base::c()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.5.1/topics/c) function.

### Load mikmart's PR version of `purrr::pmap()`

After reading [pmap strips `Date`](https://github.com/tidyverse/purrr/issues/358), it looks like someone very awesome [submitted a pull request](https://github.com/tidyverse/purrr/pull/554) to resolve this issue within a refactored version of the indexing that happens under the hood in [`purrr::pmap()`](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/map2.html).

Using [`devtools::dev_mode()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/devtools/versions/1.13.3/topics/dev_mode), you can install [`mikmart/purrr`'s "pmap" branch](https://github.com/mikmart/purrr/tree/pmap) version of `purrr` to retain Date objects while using `pmap()`.

```
# ******pmap() example ****
# load necessary packages -----
library(devtools)
library(lubridate)

# enter dev mode so you don't have to uninstall the cran version of purrr ----
dev_mode(on = TRUE)

# install mikmart's PR to fix the coercing of Dates to integer ----
install_github(repo = "mikmart/purrr", ref = "pmap")

# load mikmart's PR version of purrr ----
library(purrr)

# load necessary data
x <- data.frame(d1 = lubridate::ymd(c("2018-01-01","2018-02-01")))

# for the first column in x ----
# give me each element
# note: no need for c()
list.of.dates <-
  x %>%
  pmap(.f = ~ .x)

# view results -----
list.of.dates
# [[1]]
# [1] "2018-01-01"
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "2018-02-01"

# view the class of each list -----
map_chr(list.of.dates, class) # [1] "Date" "Date"
#
# 
# turn off dev mode ---
dev_mode(on = FALSE)
#
# restart R -----
# Manually hit Shift+Cmd+F10 or point in click under the "Session" tab
#
# clear global environment ----
rm(list = ls())
#
# ******map() example********
# load necessary packages -----
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

# load necessary data ----
x <- data.frame(d1 = lubridate::ymd(c("2018-01-01","2018-02-01")))

# from the first column ------
# give me each element
# and ensure the dates don't get coerced to integers
list.of.dates <-
  x$d1 %>%
  map(.f = ~ .x %>% c()) 

# view results -----
list.of.dates
# [[1]]
# [1] "2018-01-01"
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "2018-02-01"

# # view the class of each list -----
map_chr(list.of.dates, class) # [1] "Date" "Date"

# end of script #
```

Comment: Very interesting handling of the package update process (as it wasn't updated at purrr, yet), and made it to my notes. The  `ref = 'pmap'` in the  `install_github(repo = "mikmart/purrr", ref = "pmap")` call suggests it was just the refactored pmap function that was installed; am I reading this correctly?

Comment: @Chris that's correct. Looks like the refactoring of indexing took place in the [`src/map.c`](https://github.com/tidyverse/purrr/pull/554/files#diff-ed6bf403234aac5ffa77de8c10222317R193) script.

Comment: Great Cristian. I think your description and code above would make this entirely explicit by editing to `# load mikmart's PR version of purrr pmap ----`, and all ambiguity is gone.