# Assigned value to list of a converted Date object differs from that of a returned value in function

Tags: r, list, function, web-scraping, rvest

I have a function which returns numerous attributes of an athlete, one of them being their birth date, through web scraping off the official IAAF athletics page. I've modified it slightly for the purposes of this question:

```
upscope_list <- list()

library(xml2)
library(tidyverse)
library(stringi)
library(rvest)

scrape_function_mod <- function(athlete_name) {
  
  starting_name <- stri_trans_general(athlete_name, "latin-ascii")
  
  initial_url <-
    paste0("https://www.iaaf.org/athletes/search?query=", starting_name)
  initial_search_page <- read_html(initial_url)
  
  rawnodes_text <-
    initial_search_page %>% html_nodes("table td") %>% html_text(trim = T) %>% stri_trans_general("latin-ascii")
  
  name_split <- as_vector(strsplit(starting_name, " ", fixed = T))
  number <- which(sapply(rawnodes_text, function(x)
    grepl(name_split[1], x, ignore.case = T) &
      grepl(name_split[length(name_split)], x, ignore.case = T)))
  
  upscope_list[[athlete_name]][["birth_date"]] <<-
    rawnodes_text[(number + 4)] %>% as.Date("%d %B %Y")
  
  return(rawnodes_text[(number + 4)] %>% as.Date("%d %B %Y"))
  
}
```

Most of the function code isn't that important except for the last two lines. If I run:

```
> scrape_function_mod("Ashton Eaton")
[1] "1988-01-21"
```

This returns a proper Date object of the athlete's birth date, however the value which I insert into the list created at the start differs, by returning a numeric four digit number which I can't make sense of.

```
> upscope_list[["Ashton Eaton"]][["birth_date"]]
[1] 6594
```

You can see that what I assign to the list compared to what I return should be virtually identical but it's not. Any tips to get it to convert properly inside the function?

Comment: Ok I just realised that the number represents days since Unix/Epoch time of 01/01/1970. I still don't know why it converts it to that though.

Comment: For the bounty I'm interested as well as to the theoretical reasons why this conversion occurs. Something to do with Dates being an S3 object?

Comment: its just the numeric value: `as.numeric(as.Date("1988-01-21"))` see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52579980/date-column-coerced-to-numeric-when-indexing-dataframe-with-and-a-vector

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comment your date is converted to numeric

```
> as.numeric(as.Date("1988-01-21"))
[1] 6594
```

It is a known issue, see here:

- https://github.com/tidyverse/purrr/issues/358
- [Date column coerced to numeric when indexing dataframe with [[ and a vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52579980/date-column-coerced-to-numeric-when-indexing-dataframe-with-and-a-vector)

The known issue can be best demonstrated with hadleys example: https://github.com/tidyverse/purrr/issues/358#issuecomment-363091446:

```
> x <- list(as.Date("1988-01-21"))
> x[[1]]
[1] "1988-01-21"
> x[[c(1, 1)]]
[1] 6594
```

As you can see in the thread the issue was solved for `pmap` in `purr`r`. You could switch to that package or Maybe you are fine assigning the variable in a different way?

Answer (score 1):

To understand the exact issue let's take a simple example.

Consider a list `abc` and let's assign a date object with name `var1`

**Case 1:**

```
abc <- list()
abc[["var1"]] <- Sys.Date()
abc
#$var1
#[1] "2019-11-28"
```

This works fine as expected. Even the `class` is "Date"

```
class(abc$var1)
#[1] "Date"
```

Now let's go one level deeper.

**Case 2:**

```
abc <- list()
abc[["var1"]][["var2"]] <- Sys.Date()
abc
#$var1
# var2 
#18228
```

Here, date is converted into number. We all know that dates are internally stored as numbers but why did it work for the first one and not for the second one? Let's take another example

**Case 3:**

```
abc <- list()
abc[["var1"]] <- list()
abc[["var1"]][["var2"]] <- Sys.Date()
abc
#$var1
#$var1$var2
#[1] "2019-11-28"
```

Ahhh...I think we are now understanding the pattern and how it works. So from above cases it looks like you need to have the parent element in the list defined to maintain the Date class of element otherwise it coerces dates into numbers.  But now let me make it more confusing/interesting/complicated.

**Case 4:**

```
abc <- list()
abc[["var1"]][["var2"]] <- c(Sys.Date(), Sys.Date())
abc
#$var1
#$var1$var2
#[1] "2019-11-28" "2019-11-28"
```

and now this works too. Here we didn't define `var1` earlier but still it maintained the class of `abc$var1$var2`. How ? Why ?

The answer to everything above is documented in `?Extract`

> When $<- is applied to a NULL x, it first coerces x to list(). This is what also happens with [[<- if the replacement value value is of length greater than one: if value has length 1 or 0, x is first coerced to a zero-length vector of the type of value.

So to summarise when you are assigning value of length more than 1, it will coerce `x` to list and then assign value. If you check `class(abc$var1)` in Case 2 it is of type of `'numeric'` whereas in Case 3 and case 4 it is of type `list`. In case 3 it is of type `list` because `abc$var1` is not `NULL` whereas in case 4 `abc$var1` is `NULL` but it's length is more than 1.

Although the answer is very lengthy but I hope this explanation was helpful and easy to understand. Special thanks to [@Roland](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1412059/roland) who pointed me to the relevant help page.

---

Aside to OP for

> Any tips to get it to convert properly inside the function?

Usually using `<<-` is not a good practice and there are lot of discussions around that available on the internet. But to solve the current problem you can add a line in your function

```
library(xml2)
library(tidyverse)
library(stringi)
library(rvest)

upscope_list <- list()
scrap_function_mod <- function(athlete_name) {

  starting_name <- stri_trans_general(athlete_name, "latin-ascii")

  initial_url <- paste0("https://www.iaaf.org/athletes/search?query=", starting_name)
  initial_search_page <- read_html(initial_url)

 rawnodes_text <-
initial_search_page %>% html_nodes("table td") %>% html_text(trim = T) %>% stri_trans_general("latin-ascii")

  name_split <- as_vector(strsplit(starting_name, " ", fixed = T))
  number <- which(sapply(rawnodes_text, function(x)
      grepl(name_split[1], x, ignore.case = T) &
      grepl(name_split[length(name_split)], x, ignore.case = T)))
  upscope_list[[athlete_name]] <<- list() #Added a line here
  upscope_list[[athlete_name]][["birth_date"]] <<-
      rawnodes_text[(number + 4)] %>% as.Date("%d %B %Y")

  return(rawnodes_text[(number + 4)] %>% as.Date("%d %B %Y"))

}
```

Now when you call the function you get

```
scrap_function_mod("Ashton Eaton")
#[1] "1988-01-21"

upscope_list[["Ashton Eaton"]][["birth_date"]]
#[1] "1988-01-21"
```