# Unlist behaviour on vctr_rcrd class objects

Tags: r, vctrs

I have a vctr_record type object that I want to serve as input for code I can't/shouldn't change.

The problem I'm having is, that the lapply-then-unlist behaviour in [that code](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/blob/660aad2db2b3495ae0d8040915a40d247133ffc0/R/layout.R#L309-L311) is causing my vctr_record type object to be flattened. However that is not behaviour that I want, I want that the vctr_record type is preserved after unlisting.

I'm aware of why [unlist doesn't preserve attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15659783/why-does-unlist-kill-dates-in-r) or such, but I'm hoping somebody would know a workaround that doesn't involve me filing a github issue that can take quite some time to turn around.

Below is an example of this behaviour:

```r
library(vctrs)

# Setting up a constructor
facvec <- function(f) {
  vec_assert(f, partial_factor())
  new_rcrd(fields = list(f = f), class = "facvec")
}

# Setting up how facvec's should be combined
# Based on: https://vctrs.r-lib.org/articles/s3-vector.html
vec_ptype2.facvec <- function(x, y, ...) UseMethod("vec_ptype2.facvec", y)
vec_ptype2.facvec.default <- function(x, y, ..., x_arg = "x", y_arg = "y") {
  vec_default_ptype2(x, y, x_arg = x_arg, y_arg = y_arg)
}
vec_ptype2.facvec.facvec <- function(x, y, ...) {
  facvec(f = vec_c(field(x, "f"), field(y, "f")))
}

# Just for prettier printing
format.facvec <- function(x) {
  field(x, "f")
}

# Some dummy data
a <- facvec(factor(c("a", "b")))
b <- facvec(factor(c("c")))

# The problematic operation
unlist(list(a, b))
#> f1 f2  f 
#>  a  b  c 
#> Levels: a b c

# What I would like the unlist to return
c(a, b)
#> <facvec[3]>
#> [1] a b c
#> Levels: a b c
```

<sup>Created on 2019-12-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

The problem gets worse as more fields are added to the vctr_record type object.

Is there maybe some smart trick in the vctrs package that can help me get around this problem? I'm afraid I really can't change the unlist in the other code.

Comment: If you are concerned with more than 2 vectors in a `list`, then use `do.call(c, list(a, b))`

Comment: That is a good suggestion. However I'm not in control of how the data is being unlisted; the code that I'm trying to shepard the object through uses unlist.

Comment: According to the documention in `vctrs`, `vec_c` is used for binding `vec_c(a, b)`

Comment: Indeed, and `vec_c(!!!list(a, b))` is the vctrs equivalent of unlist

Comment: Or if you use `reduce` `reduce(list(a, b), vec_c)`