# Change tz in tibble using lubridate

Tags: r, tidyverse, lubridate, tibble

I have a tibble like the following obtained from `library(nycflights13)`:

```
   arr_time             dep_tz            arr_tz             
   <dttm>               <chr>             <chr>              
 1 2013-01-01 03:30:00  America/New_York  America/Chicago    
 2 2013-01-01 03:50:00  America/New_York  America/Chicago    
 3 2013-01-01 04:23:00  America/New_York  America/New_York   
 4 2013-01-01 05:04:00  America/New_York  America/Puerto_Rico
 5 2013-01-01 03:12:00  America/New_York  America/New_York  
 ...with 328,053 more rows
```

I want to change the `tzone` from `arr_time` to the one indicated in `arr_tz`.

I've been testing the function `with_tz()` from `lubridate` but no success.

Any help? Thanks in advance,

Alberto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `map2`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(lubridate)
df1 %>%
     mutate(arr_time = map2(arr_time, arr_tz, ~ with_tz(.x, tzone = .y)))
```

Comment: @AlbertoTorrejonValenzuela it is inside a `list` because a column cannot have different time zone

Comment: When I ```unlist()``` I lose the ```<dttm>``` format. What can I use to unlist so I can work with the format I want? By the way, thank you so much.

Comment: Here's a way to keep the date format: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15659783/why-does-unlist-kill-dates-in-r Thank you @akrun !

Comment: @AlbertoTorrejonValenzuela you can use `do.call`,  but I was concerned whether it would keep the `tz` intact