# Parsing with nested lapply

Tags: r, function, date, lapply

I have a df with multiple vars containing dates.
Among these vars some report multiple dates separated by formatting symbols.
For each cell in each of the relevant vars, I would like to split the string, reformat as data, and pick the last date.

**DATA**

```
data <- data.frame(ex=c(1,2),date_1 = c("30/12/1997\n22/12/1998","15/12/1993"), date_2 = c("21/03/1997\n11/04/1996\n11/04/1996\n11/04/1996\n11/04/1996",NA))
expected <- data.frame(ex=c(1,2),date_1 = c("1998-12-22","1993-12-15"), date_2 = c("1997-03-21",NA))
```

**CODE ATTEMPTED (1)** ERROR: ALL ENTRIES GET THE VAR MAX VALUE NOT THE CELL MAX VALUE

```
data[grep("date",names(data),value = T)] <- lapply(data[grep("date",names(data),value = T)], function(x) max(as.Date(str_split(x,"\n")[[1]],format="%d/%m/%Y"), na.rm = T))
```

**CODE ATTEMPTED (2)** (NESTED LAPPLY) ERROR: CODE BREAKS DOWN SOMEWHERE

```
data[grep("date",names(data),value = T)] <- lapply(data[grep("date",names(data),value = T)], function(y) max(y, lapply(data[grep("date",names(data),value = T)], function(x) 
as.Date(str_split(x,"\n")[[1]],format="%d/%m/%Y"), na.rm = T)))
```

**CODE ATTEMPTED (3)** (NESTED LAPPLY) ERROR: CODE BREAKS DOWN SOMEWHERE

```
data[grep("date",names(data),value = T)] <- lapply(data[grep("date",names(data),value = T)], function(y) max(y,function(x) as.Date(str_split(x,"\n")[[1]],format="%d/%m/%Y"), na.rm = T))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use :

```
data[-1] <- lapply(data[-1], function(y) sapply(strsplit(y ,"\n"), 
                               function(x) max(as.Date(x, "%d/%m/%Y"))))
data[-1] <- lapply(data[-1], as.Date)
data
#  ex     date_1     date_2
#1  1 1998-12-22 1997-03-21
#2  2 1993-12-15       <NA>
```

The logic is the same as described for every column (except first) we split the string on `"\n"`, convert to date and return the `max` value. The inner `sapply` loop returns numeric representation of dates so we use another `lapply` to convert the numbers to date.

Comment: Thanks, the first line of code works (after transforming the cols in catacter). However, I get the pure numeric format (See:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15659783/why-does-unlist-kill-dates-in-r) that the second bit cannon convert back.

Am I working with some wrong settings?

Comment: It works, specifying this origin. 
data[-1] <- lapply(data[-1], function(x) as.Date(x,origin = "1970-01-01"))

Comment: Just call library(zoo), before embarking

Comment: ohh...thats strange. It worked for me without specifying the origin. Maybe I have some different setting.