# How to unlist a list of mixed types without losing those types?

Tags: r, list

Suppose that you have a list of mixed types, say `list("Alice",64,c(11L,12L))` and you want to unlist these, to get something like `"Alice", 64 , c(11L,12L)` as your output. R's `unlist` is inadequate for this because it will coerce all of your inputs in to strings and therefore output `"Alice" "64"    "11"    "12"`.

I know of [a few hacks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15659783/10319707) for fixing this problem when your type are not mixed, but what can be done in a mixed-type case like this? If this is not possible with a list, is there a more general "list" type that could be used instead?

Edit: Comments have rightly pointed out that having "something like `"Alice", 64 , c(11L,12L)` as your output" is the whole point of the list type. However, I want these outputted to the terminal, rather than outputted as a single object that stores all of these items. Is this possible?

Comment: Unlist them to *where*? There is no problem assigning them to variables individually, but of course if you want to assign the unlisted thing to a vector you would need to have a common type.

Comment: I'm having difficulty understanding your question. A list is object class that exists to deal with this problem. What issue are you trying to solve? Perhaps `tibble(column = list("Alice",64,c(11L,12L)))` would be more to your liking?

Comment: @JohnColeman Excellent point. I want them as the output of a function, straight to the terminal.

Comment: @IanCampbell I want them as the output of a function, straight to the terminal. My goal is to take a list's elements (not the list itself), shuffle them, and output the elements again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to print the elements, you could use `lapply` and `dput`:

```
invisible(lapply(list("Alice",c(11L,12L),64,c(11,13,12),list(A = 2,B = 3)), dput))
#"Alice"
#11:12
#64
#c(11, 13, 12)
#list(A = 2, B = 3)
```