# How to keep zero-length element when using c() on a list?

Tags: r

**Context:** I have a list of Dates objects as an ouput from a function. Some of them can be `Date of length 0`.

**Problem:** When I concatenate the elements of the list to get a vector (*i.e.* `do.call(c, mylist)`), the latters are dropped. This cause problems when I try to add this vector as a column in a pre-existing dataframe.

**Question:** Is it possible to "keep" these `Date of length 0` elements into the final vector? Do you know a better way to acheive the expected result?

```r
ex_list <- list(structure(14467, class = "Date"), 
                structure(14567, class = "Date"),
                structure(numeric(0), class = "Date"))
ex_list
#> [[1]]
#> [1] "2009-08-11"
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] "2009-11-19"
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> Date of length 0
ex_vector <- do.call(c, ex_list)
ex_vector # the Date of length 0 is dropped
#> [1] "2009-08-11" "2009-11-19"
df <- data.frame(id = c("A", "B", "C"))
df$dates <- ex_vector
#> Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, dates, value = structure(c(14467, 14567: le tableau de remplacement a 2 lignes, le tableau remplacé en a 3
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

**Expected output:**

| id | dates |
| --- | --- |
| A | 2009-08-11 |
| B | 2009-11-19 |
| C | NA |

Comment: Replace  `numeric(0)` with `NA_real_` and `df <- data.frame(id = c("A", "B", "C"), dates=unlist(ex_list))` works for me.

Comment: @Limey sorry I was not clear in my question. the list of dates is an output from a function and I expect many situations like the one illustrated by the mocked list. In addition, I use the `do.call(c, ex_list)` to preserve the date format (is it better to use `unlist()` and then convert it back to dates?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For use in a data frame you'd prefer `NA`'s over `Date(0)`. E.g.

```r
ex_list[sapply(ex_list, rlang::is_empty)] <- NA
ex_vector <- do.call(c, ex_list)
df <- data.frame(id = c("A", "B", "C"))
df$dates <- ex_vector
```

Or a `tidyverse`-solution:

```r
library(tidyverse)

data.frame(id = c("A", "B", "C")) |>
  add_column(as_tibble_col(ex_list, column_name = "dates")) |>
  unnest(dates, keep_empty = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea, however, I think the `ex_vector <- do.call(c, ex_list)` is still needed to preserve the Date format.

Comment: Yes, or `unlist()`, sorry for missing this

Comment: In fact, `unlist()`  also kills Date format, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/15659783/10264278. Thus I use `do.call(c, ex_list)`.

Comment: Seems like I have nothing more to add than the `NA` point ;)

Comment: @Paul I realized that we could solve some of your "problems" by using tibbles. This will keep your list of dates as a nested list allowing you do deal with it afterwards: Here by unnesting it, but that's just one possibility.