# Why sapply returns numeric when applied to Dates?

Tags: r, date, lubridate

NB: This question is about `sapply`, not about 'unlist` and the answer to this question was provided in comment (that sapply uses unlist). Hence, I believe it IS NOT a duplicate of the [Why does unlist() turn date types into numeric?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15659783/why-does-unlist-kill-dates-in-r) question. Please remove ' Duplicate question' so i can post and accept the asnwer.

---

Can anyone explain the logic and the reason why in R the following line returns numeric and not Date, as expected?

```
set.seed(0); sapply(1:4, function(x) lubridate::ymd("2023-01-01")) %>% str()

num [1:4] 19358 19358 19358 19358
```

That means that I have to apply `as.Date (date, origin)` to convert these numericals back to Dates, which I dont want to do.

I encountered this problem trying to generate a set of random dates:

```
generateRandomDate <- function(start_date, end_date) {
  random_days <- sample(0:(end_date - start_date), 1)
  start_date + days(random_days)
}
```

using this line:

```
sapply(1:12, function(x) generateRandomDate2(ymd("2023-01-01"), ymd("2023-1-31")))
```

So in order to fix this problem, I needed to write:

```
set.seed(0); sapply(1:12, function(x) generateRandomDate(ymd("2023-01-01"), ymd("2023-1-31")) ) %>% as.Date(origin = "1970-01-01"))
```

which is contre-intuative and over-complicated...

Comment: `sapply` uses `simplify2array` under the hood. This of course in turn uses `unlist` which ends up stripping off the class attribute before converting into the relevant structure.

Comment: helpful link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15659783/why-does-unlist-kill-dates-in-r

Comment: This is a usecase for purrr package; `purrr::map_vec(1:4, \(x) lubridate::ymd("2023-01-01"))`